# Passing argument for webcomponents in Hybrid JS

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm trying to create a web component using the Hybrid framework. https://hybrids.js.org/

In my component, I am have a value called basketPrice.

MyExample.js looks like this (- the imports and a few functions above)

```
export const MyExample = {
fate: false,
basketPrice: '0.00',
visibility : 'hidden',
render: ({ basketPrice }) => html`

<button onclick="${expandCardPanel}">Expand</button>
<div id="cardPanel" class="hidden">
  <input type="text" placeholder="cardnumber">
  Total price: ${basketPrice}!
  <button onclick="${setFate}">Test</button>
</div>
`,
};
```

When referencing the web component from index.html,I give the argument:

```
<my-example basketPrice="10.00"></my-example>
```

This isn't picking up the argument I'm passing through, and the page is displaying:

```
Total price: 0.00
```

I am not sure why this is.  According to this snippet from the hybrid site, this should be fine:
https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-counter-web-component-built-with-hybrids-library-co2ow?file=/src/SimpleCounter.js

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: and when you name your variables all lowercase?

Comment: unbelievable.... that worked.  has to be all lowercase.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks so much, worked.  Have I missed that in the docs?

Comment: I don't know Hybrids details. Problem is; with a Framework or Library you learn the **sugar-syntax**. Had you started with Vanilla JavaScript you would have learned this yourself on day 1. That's is the main reason I always suggest to learn the core technology first, and only when you understand what you are doing (optionally) continue with a framework/library that makes development life "easier" (and then with the next upgrade you learn they made breaking changes from Lit 2.0 to 3.0 and you have to refactor code) Good knowledge of Vanilla Web Components will last another 25 JavaScript years.

Comment: I went through 'A shot of code' building web components with vanilla js on youtube, and had built what I wanted. Understood it too.  However, there was no mention of this through that.  I'm only using Hybrid follow the "write less code" principal.

Comment: But write **less** means **more** dependencies... and if you don't know which code you depend on... https://www.sciencealert.com/how-a-programmer-almost-broke-the-internet-by-deleting-11-lines-of-code